# Send py2app application to Mac without python

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, py2app

I have a tkinter application, which I would like to distribute to my colleagues, who do not have python installed.
I use py2app with the following setup.py file

```py
from setuptools import setup

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

#APP would be the name of the file your code is in.
APP = ['Doughnut_stress.py']
DATA_FILES = ['C20.icns']
#The Magic is in OPTIONS.
OPTIONS = {
    'packages': ['tkinter', 'matplotlib'],
    'includes': ['tkinter'],
    'argv_emulation': False,
    'iconfile': 'C20.icns', #change app.icns to the image file name!!!
    'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': 'Axial bearing program',
        'CFBundleDisplayName': 'Axial bearing program',
        'CFBundleGetInfoString': "Calculates C20 axial bearing",
        'CFBundleVersion': "0.0.0",
        'CFBundleShortVersionString': "0.0.0",
        'NSHumanReadableCopyright': u"Copyright © 2020, Component 2.0 A/S, All Rights Reserved"
    }
    }

setup(
    app=APP,
    name='Axial bearing program', #change to anything
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

I then use

```sh
python setup.py py2app
```

to compile the program into an app. Note I have symlinked python to python3. My python 3 is version 3.7.5 and is installed through MacPorts. py2app is version 0.20, and tkinter is version 8.6

The program compiles fine, and I can run it from terminal, or just double-click on the app file, and it works as intended.

However, when I send it to my colleague and try to open it from his computer by double-clicking the app, I get a pop up where I can choose to "Open Console" or "Terminate".
If I run the program through terminal (by running APP_NAME.app/Contents/MacOS/APP_NAME) I get the following error

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/prm/Downloads/Component 2.0 axial bearing program.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 416, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/prm/Downloads/Component 2.0 axial bearing program.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 394, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/prm/Downloads/Component 2.0 axial bearing program.app/Contents/Resources/Doughnut_stress.py", line 31, in <module>
    root = Tk()
  File "tkinter/__init__.pyc", line 2023, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    /opt/local/lib/tcl8.6 {/Users/prm/Downloads/Component 2.0 axial bearing program.app/Contents/lib/tcl8.6} {/Users/prm/Downloads/Component 2.0 axial bearing program.app/lib/tcl8.6} {/Users/prm/Downloads/Component 2.0 axial bearing program.app/Contents/library} {/Users/prm/Downloads/Component 2.0 axial bearing program.app/library} {/Users/prm/Downloads/Component 2.0 axial bearing program.app/tcl8.6.9/library} /Users/prm/Downloads/tcl8.6.9/library



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.

2020-01-20 15:54:28.439 Component 2.0 axial bearing program[34251:2906750] Component 2.0 axial bearing program Error
```

I can also run the included python file in APP_NAME.app/Contents/MacOS/python, which yield this error

```sh
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000000010d0f8dc0 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
```

Someone else posted about this on Reddit some time ago, but no answer came up https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/c1on6f/py2app_in_a_mac_without_python/

How can I fix this, so I can distribute my python application?

Comment: I don't have mac to test, but you can try to add include 'tcl'; 'tkinter' might not be enough; may be something more needed

Comment: I will try to add it, and once I can access my colleague's computer I will test it out

Comment: @Drako I have tried 'tcl' to includes in the setup file, however, I still get the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same issue (missing init.tcl) on my setup:

- macOS 10.15.5, venv with Python 3.7.7 interpreter (includes TCL8.6), py2app 0.21
- It turns out that TCL is not copied neither to venv nor to .app by py2app, so the generated .app is finding TCL in Python installation directory (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/tcl8.6) on my setup.

  - however this is not available on the setups without Python installation -> **error**

### Solution

When I've manually copied:

```
- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/tcl8
- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/tcl8.6
- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/tk8.6
```

to

```
- path_to_venv/lib
```

py2app will take it from there and store it in the .app in this location:

```
- path_to_project/dist/myApp.app/Contents/Resources/lib/
```

and from here it is found by the python code

### Next steps

I see 2 main options how to automate it:

1. In py2app setup file implement a check for the TCL availability in the venv structure and copy it from the system location if not available
2. Implement it directly in py2app

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks.
However, my tcl8, tcl8.6 and tk8.6 folders were located at /opt/local/lib/
The location can be found by opening python and running the following commands:
```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
print(root.tk.exprstring('$tcl_library'))
print(root.tk.exprstring('$tk_library'))
```

Comment: Yes, the TCL and TK location will depend on the way Python and TCL has been installed. I've used an installer from python.org.

Comment: I've installed Python through macports. However I thought that the information might help someone else with the same problem, which is why I also left some code which can be used to locate the folders.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you, except I was using `pygame`. Here's a quick fix:

Instead of simply `python setup.py py2app`, try:

**`python setup.py py2app --packages="encodings"`**

(For me I did `python setup.py py2app --packages="pygame"` and it worked)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Tcl error trying to run .app bundle built in my setup:

- MacOS BigSur, python3.11, python-tk, venv with python3.11, py2app

As mentioned above, for different TCL/TK locations dependant on your installs, you may simply rely on py2app finding of the tcl path on your machine, which is given as the 1st path in the error log:

- _tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:

  **/opt/local/lib/tcl8.6** .......

With that, open new terminal at <your_venv>/lib directory and link tcl/tk libraries from that path to your venv as follows:

```
ln -s /opt/local/lib/tcl8.6 tcl8.6
ln -s /opt/local/lib/tk8.6 tk8.6
```